# Change input value on Wordpress' get_search_form()

Tags: css, wordpress, input, submit

Trying to use the new get_search_form() function on WordPress, I noticed I can't remove the textual label from the search submit button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it partially working with:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
$("input#searchsubmit").attr("value","");
```

Still, the value disappearance takes WAY too much time. How can I get rid of it in the first place?

Comment: Got it! Added display:none to the search, gave it some hidden space to run the script, and at the end I simply toggled it to show.

This way it a modification in the WP core is prevented.

Answer (score 3):

the quick and easy is to create a new template named `searchform.php` in your theme directory.

in that way `get_search_form()` will load your form instead of the default one.